# "the" before "condition"

Tags: grammar

Should we write "the" before the word "condition"? that is,if two conditions A and B are known which of the following is correct?
Conditions A and B.
or
The Condition A and B.

Comment: Because *Condition A* and *Condition B* appear to be proper nouns, they need no article (the).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that "condition" is proper.

Comment: It is a proper noun in your examples, but be aware that it is not always so.  Someone else may be more apt to explain the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible. If you regard "Condition A" as the name of the condition, then, as Anonym says, it doesn't want *the*. If you regard "A" as the name, and "condition" just as a description of what kind of thing "A" is, then it wants *the*.

I think the former is more common.